# Bower component installed but missing from index.html

Tags: angularjs, bower, lodash

I've installed `lodash` using bower to my **angularjs** app:

```
bower install --save lodash
```

bower.json is updated accordingly:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.11.2",
    "angular": "~1.4.0",
    "json3": "~3.2.4",
    "jquery": "~1.10.0",
    "sass-bootstrap": "~3.0.0",
    "es5-shim": "~2.1.0",
    "angular-resource": "~1.4.0",
    "angular-cookies": "~1.4.0",
    "angular-sanitize": "~1.4.0",
    "angular-route": "~1.4.0",
    "angular-ui": "~0.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "~1.4.0",
    "angular-scenario": "~1.4.0"
  }
}
```

A `lodash` directory is added to the `bower_components` directory and I've run `grunt server`. However, the `<script>` tag for lodash is not added to `index.html`.

How do I add `lodash` to my app after it's installed with bower? FWIW, I've installed other frontend components successfully and haven't hit this problem, so either I'm doing something differently or my environment has changed.

I'm unsure how to investigate this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it manually or use [Grunt Wiredep](https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-wiredep) task. If your app is already configured with wiredep task then just run `grunt wiredep`

Comment: I have other frontend components (jquery, angular, etc) that were injected into index.html without wiredep. Why is this needed now? The Yeoman documentation makes no mention of the need to install wiredep either.

Comment: Can you list the tasks registered in your `build` task in `Gruntfile.js`?

Comment: Pulling out tasks registered with `grunt.registerTask`, they are `server, test, build, default`.

Comment: Yes, I want the associated tasks registerd with the `build` task. That should be a list like `['clean:dist', 'useminPrepare']` etc.

Comment: `'clean:dist',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'autoprefixer',
    'concat',
    'ngmin',
    'copy:dist',
    'cdnify',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'rev',
    'usemin'`

Comment: Not sure, how those frontend components were previously injected.